# AWS Lambda error "iam property does not exist" when accessing iam Cognito attribute that I know exists

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am getting an error while trying to access an object that I know exists.

When trying to access the `iam` property of the event.authorizer object returned from AWS Cognito, an error displays in both VS Code and the terminal once I run it.

```
src/private.ts:9:33 - error TS2339: Property 'iam' does not exist on type '{ jwt: { claims: { [name: string]: string | number | boolean | string[]; }; scopes: string[]; }; }'.ts(2339)
```

This error is especially puzzling, because when I print the "event" object, it shows evidence that it exists.

**Output of `event.requestContext`:**

`{"statusCode":200,"headers":{"Content-type":"text/json"},"body":"{\"event\":{\"accountId\":\"365416766059\",\"apiId\":\"8ihwuguj40\",\"authorizer\":{\"iam\":{\"accessKey\":\"ASIAVKFE... 1068 more characters"}`

This shows that there is an object `iam` that is the value of the `authorizer` attribute. This is proof that it exists. So why does VS Code have an issue with it?

---

I ran the code using `npx sst start` which runs the code with no issues, and returns the expected `event` object with `authorizer` and `awt` nested objects.

Full code for lambda function is below.

```
import { APIGatewayProxyHandlerV2 } from "aws-lambda"

export const handler: APIGatewayProxyHandlerV2 = async (event) => {
  const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)

  const authoriser = event.requestContext.authorizer


  const accountId = authoriser?.iam.accountId ?? "" // Problem starts with reference to "iam" here.
 

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {"Content-type": "text/json"},
    body: JSON.stringify({ message: `Private random number: ${rand}`, accountId: accountId}),
  }
}
```

I have tried:

- Making `iam` an optional by appending a question mark.
- Using a try-catch block around the statement.

Comment: Can you try `const authoriser = JSON.parse(event.requestContext.authorizer)`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I tried that and I got:

`Argument of type '{ jwt: { claims: { [name: string]: string | number | boolean | string[]; }; scopes: string[]; }; } | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event` is mis-typed.

By typing your function as `APIGatewayProxyHandlerV2`, you have told typescript that `event` is of type `APIGatewayProxyEventV2` ([typedef here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/f318642d8e03ed3ed4fa95dd27f12ddd99447d6e/types/aws-lambda/trigger/api-gateway-proxy.d.ts#L124)).  The actual `event` from Lambda you are getting is not that type, as evident from the log output.

```js
// what typescript thinks your event is:
export interface APIGatewayProxyEventV2 {
    version: string;
    routeKey: string;
    rawPath: string;
    rawQueryString: string;
    cookies?: string[] | undefined;
    headers: APIGatewayProxyEventHeaders;
    queryStringParameters?: APIGatewayProxyEventQueryStringParameters | undefined;
    requestContext: {
        accountId: string;
        apiId: string;
        authorizer?: {
            jwt: {
                claims: { [name: string]: string | number | boolean | string[] };
                scopes: string[];
            };
        } | undefined;
        domainName: string;
        domainPrefix: string;
        ...etc
```

So you need to fix the `event` type.  What are your options?

1. Search for a pre-defined type that matches the lambda event
2. Be lazy and self-hating:  `event: any`
3. Define a minimum type that satisfies the contract:  `event: MyLambdaEvent`

```js
// custom event type
// match the required parts of the event object lambda is actually giving you
interface MyLambdaEvent {
  authorizer: {
    iam: {
      accountId: string
    }
  }
}
```